# How do you convert varchar string in ISO 8601 format 'ID:HH24:MI' into time?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datetime

I have a column in postgresql of type varchar that stores time in the format "ID:HH24:MI" and I would like to add/subtract time to it. For example, a value of "4:21:35" would translate to Thursday 9:35PM. If I wanted to add thirty minutes to it, I expect the string "4:22:05".

I tried the query below but it does not work because it returns the wrong day. I'm expecting 4:22:05 and it returns 6:22:05.

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp('4:21:35', 'ID:HH24:MI' ) + INTERVAL '30 minute', 'ID:HH24:MI');

6:22:05
```

How could I modify the query or change my approach to achieve the right output? I want to compare time strings in the format "ID:HH24:MI" and would like to be able to add/subtract time to those time strings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The format `ID:HH24:MI` does not specify a timestamp: The day of week is therefore ignored in `to_timestamp()` and you get a timestamp with date set to `0001-01-01`  in your example: `"0001-01-01 21:35:00+01 BC"` (which happens to be a saturday)